# VBA: avoid empty cells when creating array from pivottable

Tags: arrays, excel, is-empty, vba

I'm trying to create an array based on a pivot table with multiple empty cells, however instead of referring to previous value, the array keeps all the empty cells:

```
For AllCostTypeRowCounter = 1 To SiteRowCount

    AllCostTypeArrayCounter = AllCostTypeArrayCounter + 1

    ReDim Preserve AllCostTypeArray(2, AllCostTypeArrayCounter)

    If Not CountryRange(AllCostTypeRowCounter, 1) Is Nothing Then

        AllCostTypeArray(1, AllCostTypeArrayCounter) = CountryRange(AllCostTypeRowCounter, 1)

    Else

        AllCostTypeArray(1, AllCostTypeArrayCounter) = AllCostTypeArray(1, AllCostTypeArrayCounter - 1)

    End If

    AllCostTypeArray(2, AllCostTypeArrayCounter) = SiteRange(AllCostTypeRowCounter, 1).Value

Next AllCostTypeRowCounter
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I solved the question by changing the following code:

```
If Not CountryRange(AllCostTypeRowCounter, 1) Is Nothing Then
```

to:

```
If CountryRange(AllCostTypeRowCounter, 1) <> "" Then
```

Can anyone tell me why this change works. The above seems the same to me. Also how do I close my own post?